# Google maps set waypoints pick up time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, time, calculator

help me to solve this case -
demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aLosek26/    (explanation in the html)

how to calculate the pick up time for each stop, on the basis of pre-set arrival time on the last address ?

This is the code

```
    <style>
        html {
            height: 100%
        }
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
        .ziel {
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #0086A9;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 15px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
    <div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
        <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;padding:20px;"></div>
        <div style="padding-left:10px;">I want "pick up time" to look like this:
            <br> A to B -> pick up time: 13:12
            <br> B to C -> pick up time: 13:16
            <br> C to D -> pick up time: 13:48
            <br> D to E -> pick up time: 14:20
            <br> E to F -> pick up time: 14:32
            <br> F to G -> pick up time: 14:45
            <br>
            <br> </div>
        <div><strong>Arrival to the last address is   15:00 </strong> </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="total"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var directionDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

        function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 6,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: chicago
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            calcRoute();
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        function calcRoute() {
            var checkboxArray = ["Klosterneuburgerstrasse 3,1200 Wien", "Simon-Denk Gasse 2,1090 wien", "Favoritenstrasse 3, 1100 Wien", "Hütteldorferstrasse 4, 1140 Wien", "Summeringerhauptstrasse 3, 1110 Wien", "Kobesgase, 1220 Wien", "Ziegelhofstrasse 3, 1220 Wien"];
            var start = checkboxArray[0];
            var end = checkboxArray[checkboxArray.length - 1];
            var waypts = [];
            for(var i = 1; i < checkboxArray.length - 1; i++) {
                var adresanesto = checkboxArray[i];
                if(adresanesto !== "") {
                    waypts.push({
                        location: adresanesto,
                        stopover: true
                    });
                }
            }
            var request = {
                // from: Blackpool to: Preston to: Blackburn
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                waypoints: waypts,
                optimizeWaypoints: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    var route = response.routes[0];
                    var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
                    // For each route, display summary information.
                    var ankunft = "06:00";
                    for(var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                        var hms = ankunft; // your input string
                        var zeit = route.legs[i].duration.value;
                        var zeitx = (zeit / 60).toFixed(0);
                        var a = hms.split(':');
                        var sekunde = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60;
                        var min5x = zeitx * 60;
                        var sec_num = (+sekunde - +min5x);
                        var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
                        var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
                        var seconds = Math.floor(sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60));
                        if(hours < 10) {
                            hours = "0" + hours;
                        }
                        if(minutes < 10) {
                            minutes = "0" + minutes;
                        }
                        if(seconds < 10) {
                            seconds = "0" + seconds;
                        }
                        var vreme = hours + ':' + minutes;
                        var routeSegment = i + 1;
                        var ruta = "ruta" + routeSegment;
                        var timespan = "timespan" + routeSegment;
                        var vremespan = "vremespan" + routeSegment;
                        if(routeSegment == 1) {
                            var ziel = 'A to B';
                        }
                        if(routeSegment == 2) {
                            var ziel = 'B to C';
                        }
                        if(routeSegment == 3) {
                            var ziel = 'C to D';
                        }
                        if(routeSegment == 4) {
                            var ziel = 'D to E';
                        }
                        if(routeSegment == 5) {
                            var ziel = 'E to F';
                        }
                        if(routeSegment == 6) {
                            var ziel = 'F to G';
                        }
                        if(routeSegment == 7) {
                            var ziel = 'G to H';
                        }
                        if(routeSegment == 8) {
                            var ziel = 'H to I';
                        }
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<div id='" + ruta + "'><b><span class='ziel'> " + ziel + "</span></b><br /><br />";
                        // summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
                        // summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Distance: </b>" + route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br />";
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Duration: </b><span id='" + timespan + "'>" + zeitx + "</span> Min.<br />";
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Pick up time: </b><span id='" + vremespan + "'><span style='color:#ff0000'>" + vreme + "</span> <----  ???<br /><br /></div>";
                    }
                    computeTotalDistance(response);
                } else {
                    alert("directions response " + status);
                }
            });
        }

        function computeTotalDistance(result) {
            var totalDist = 0;
            var totalTime = 0;
            var myroute = result.routes[0];
            for(i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
                totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
                totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
            }
            totalDist = totalDist / 1000.
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "total distance is: " + totalDist + " km<br>total time is: " + (totalTime / 60).toFixed(0) + " minutes";
        }
    </script>
```

EDIT
explanation

we have a start address and end address and four waypoints and have variable "arrival" - arival time

arrival   15:00

A B C D E F G = different address - street number postal code city...

```
A to B   Distance: 1,2 km   Duration: 4 Min.
B to C   Distance: 13,8 km  Duration: 32 Min.
C to D   Distance: 20,3 km  Duration: 32 Min.
D to E   Distance: 6,9 km   Duration: 12 Min.
E to F   Distance: 9,1 km   Duration: 13 Min.
F to G   Distance: 6,9 km   Duration: 15 Min.
```

A is start address
B C D E and F is waypoints
G is  end address

example:

arrival time for end address is set 15:00 and duration between waypoint F and end address G 15 min then is pick up time from waypoint F is 14:45   | F to G  Pickup time 14:45

how to calculate for all waypoints ?

A to B     Pick up time ?

B to C     Pick up time ?

...

I want to look like this

A to B - Distance: 1,2 km   Duration: 4 Min.  Pick up time: 13:12

B to C - Distance: 13,8 km  Duration: 32 Min. Pick up time: 13:16

C to D - Distance: 20,3 km  Duration: 32 Min. Pick up time: 13:48

D to E - Distance: 6,9 km   Duration: 12 Min. Pick up time: 14:20

E to F - Distance: 9,1 km   Duration: 13 Min. Pick up time: 14:32

F to G - Distance: 6,9 km   Duration: 15 Min. Pick up time: 14:45

I need this for a taxi

I hope you understand what I want...

sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Your numbers don't add up to your "expected" results (the last leg is only 3 minutes long).  Please clarify what you are trying to achieve in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I do pretty much the same thing as Dr.Molle (we started writing this code at the same time).  I also iterate from finish to start.

But I want to post my code anyway.

I keep the calculations in seconds.  Only convert at the last moment; and don't use custom calculations like (hours * 3600) ... Time is tricky; there are a lot of exceptions you are not thinking of.

```
<style>
    html {
        height: 100%
    }
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
    }
    .ziel {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #0086A9;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
<div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
    <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;padding:20px;"></div>
    <div style="padding-left:10px;">I want "pick up time" to look like this:
        <br> A to B -> pick up time: 13:12
        <br> B to C -> pick up time: 13:16
        <br> C to D -> pick up time: 13:48
        <br> D to E -> pick up time: 14:20
        <br> E to F -> pick up time: 14:32
        <br> F to G -> pick up time: 14:45
        <br>
        <br> </div>
    <div><strong>Arrival to the last address is   15:00 </strong> </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="total"></div>
</div>
<script>
    var directionDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: chicago
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        calcRoute();
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function calcRoute() {
        var checkboxArray = ["Klosterneuburgerstrasse 3,1200 Wien", "Simon-Denk Gasse 2,1090 wien", "Favoritenstrasse 3, 1100 Wien", "Hütteldorferstrasse 4, 1140 Wien", "Summeringerhauptstrasse 3, 1110 Wien", "Kobesgase, 1220 Wien", "Ziegelhofstrasse 3, 1220 Wien"];
        var start = checkboxArray[0];
        var end = checkboxArray[checkboxArray.length - 1];
        var waypts = [];
        for(var i = 1; i < checkboxArray.length - 1; i++) {
            var adresanesto = checkboxArray[i];
            if(adresanesto !== "") {
                waypts.push({
                    location: adresanesto,
                    stopover: true
                });
            }
        }
        var request = {
            // from: Blackpool to: Preston to: Blackburn
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: waypts,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                var route = response.routes[0];
                var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
                summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
                // For each route, display summary information.

                var displayText = '';
                var arrival = new Date(); 

                var secondsToArrival = 0;
                // set arrival time
                arrival.setHours(15);
                arrival.setMinutes(0);
                arrival.setSeconds(0);

                // let's calculate back.  From finish to start
                for(var i = route.legs.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
                  //summaryPanel.innerHTML +=  +'s<br>';
                  secondsToArrival += route.legs[i].duration.value;
                  // new date variable.
                  var startAtWaypoint = new Date(); 
                  startAtWaypoint.setHours(arrival.getHours());
                  startAtWaypoint.setMinutes(arrival.getMinutes());
                  startAtWaypoint.setSeconds(arrival.getSeconds());

                  // calculate difference.  We subtract the seconds.
                  startAtWaypoint.setSeconds(arrival.getSeconds() - secondsToArrival);

                  switch(i) {
                      case 0: var ziel = 'A to B'; break;
                      case 1: var ziel = 'B to C'; break;
                      case 2: var ziel = 'C to D'; break;
                      case 3: var ziel = 'D to E'; break;
                      case 4: var ziel = 'E to F'; break;
                      case 5: var ziel = 'F to G'; break;
                      case 6: var ziel = 'G to H'; break;
                      case 7: var ziel = 'H to I'; break;
                      default: var ziel = '';
                  }

                  displayText = 'segment: ' + ziel 
                                + '<br>dist: ' + route.legs[i].distance.text 
                                + '<br> time segment: ' + route.legs[i].duration.value 
                                + 's <br> seconds to arrival: ' + secondsToArrival 
                                + 's <br> time at waypoint: ' + startAtWaypoint.getHours() +':'+ startAtWaypoint.getMinutes()
                                + '<hr>' + displayText;   // notice: instead of displayText+= , I put displayText at the end, because the loop is backwards
                }
                summaryPanel.innerHTML = displayText;

                computeTotalDistance(response);
            } 
            else {
                alert("directions response " + status);
            }
        });
    }
    function computeTotalDistance(result) {
        var totalDist = 0;
        var totalTime = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
        for(i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
            totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
            totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
        }
        totalDist = totalDist / 1000.
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "total distance is: " + totalDist + " km<br>total time is: " + (totalTime / 60).toFixed(0) + " minutes";
    }    
</script>
```

[example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/aLosek26/7/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 1):

How will you calculate the pickup-time for the waypoints when you don't know the duration of the next legs?

You must iterate from the last leg to the first leg.
And instead of using your complicated time-calculations you should  use the `Date`-object, that's what it's good for.

```js
function initialize() {
  var goo = google.maps,
    map = new goo.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new goo.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523),
      zoom: 6,
      noClear: true,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    }),
    service = new goo.DirectionsService(),
    renderer = new goo.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map
    });
  map.controls[goo.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT]
    .push(document.getElementById("directions_panel"));
  goo.event
    .addDomListener(document.getElementById("directions_panel"),
      'click',
      function(e) {
        var legs = this.querySelectorAll('div[id^="ruta"][data-latlng]');
        for (var i = 0; i < legs.length; ++i) {
          if (
            legs[i] == e.target ||
            legs[i].contains(e.target)
          ) {
            var latlng = legs[i]
              .getAttribute('data-latlng')
              .split(',')
            map.panTo(new goo.LatLng(latlng[0], latlng[1]));
            return;
          }
        }
      });
  calcRoute(service,
    renderer, ["Klosterneuburgerstrasse 3,1200 Wien",
      "Simon-Denk Gasse 2,1090 wien",
      "Favoritenstrasse 3, 1100 Wien",
      "Hütteldorferstrasse 4, 1140 Wien",
      "Summeringerhauptstrasse 3, 1110 Wien",
      "Kobesgase, 1220 Wien",
      "Ziegelhofstrasse 3, 1220 Wien"
    ]);
}

function calcRoute(service, renderer, route) {
  var goo = google.maps,
    request = {
      origin: route.shift(),
      destination: route.pop(),
      waypoints: (function(r) {
        var a = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < r.length; ++i) {
          a.push({
            location: r[i],
            stopover: true
          })
        }
        return a;
      }(route)),
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: goo.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

  service.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == goo.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      renderer.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];

      //parse string into a Date-object
      var arrival = (function(hm) {
          var d = new Date(),
            a = hm.split(':');
          d.setHours(parseInt(a[0]));
          d.setMinutes(parseInt(a[1]));
          d.setSeconds(0);
          return d;
        }("06:00")),
        total = {
          duration: 0,
          distance: 0
        },
        //returns the formatted pickup-time

        pickup = function(duration) {
          arrival.setTime(arrival.getTime() - (duration * 1000));

          return ([("0" + arrival.getHours()).slice(-2), 
                   ("0" + arrival.getMinutes()).slice(-2)]
            .join(':'));
        },
        html = [],
        item;

      for (var i = route.legs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        total.distance += route.legs[i].distance.value;
        total.duration += route.legs[i].duration.value;

        item = "<div data-latlng='" + 
                  route.legs[i].start_location.toUrlValue() + "' id='ruta" + 
                 (i + 1) + "'><b><span class='ziel'> " +
                 String.fromCharCode(65 + i) +
                 ' to ' +
                 String.fromCharCode(65 + 1 + i) +
                 "</span></b><br /><br />";

        item += "<b>Distance: </b>" + route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br />";
        item += "<b>Duration: </b><span id='timespan" + (i + 1) + "'>" +
          (route.legs[i].duration.value / 60).toFixed(0) +
          "</span> Min.<br />";
        item += "<b>Pick up time: </b><span id='vremespan" + (i + 1) + "'>" +
          "<span style='color:#ff0000'>" +
          pickup(route.legs[i].duration.value) + "</span><br /><br /></div>";
        html.unshift(item);
      }

      html.push(
        "<hr/>total distance is: " + (total.distance / 1000).toFixed(1) +
        " km<br>total time is: " +
        (total.duration / 60).toFixed(0) + " minutes")+'<br/><hr/>';
      document.getElementById("directions_panel").innerHTML = html.join('');

    } else {
      document.getElementById("directions_panel") = "directions response:" + status;
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
.ziel {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #0086A9;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#directions_panel {
  height:60%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #FFEE77;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 5px 50px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_canvas">
  <div id="directions_panel"></div>
</div>
```